# Branch twice for unique condition

Tags: design-patterns, php, conditions

Consider an application that displays only Foobars belonging to themselves to normal users, and all Foobars to admins:

```
-- Normal users:
SELECT * FROM Foobar WHERE user_id=:user_id;

-- Admins:
SELECT * FROM Foobar;
```

Currently, this how the queries are represented in the codebase:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Foobar";

if ( $user['type']!='admin' ) {
    $sql.= ' WHERE user_id=:user_id';
}

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

if ( $user['type']!='admin' ) {
    $stmt->bindValue(':user_id', $user['id']);
}
```

I do not like this dual-branching approach from a maintainability standpoint. For instance, a bug like typing `$user['type']=='admin'` instead of `$user['type']!='admin'` would have to be found and fixed in two places instead of one. However, I also don't like the idea of separate functions for each case: admins and regular users.

A third approach would be to branch once and there create the SQL to add and the values to bind:

```
$sql_to_add = '';
$array_to_bind = array();

if ( $user['type']!='admin' ) {
    $sql_to_add = ' WHERE user_id=:user_id';
    $array_to_bind = array( ':user_id'=>$user['id'] );
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Foobar {$sql_to_add}";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

foreach ( $array_to_bind as $k=>$v ) {
    $stmt->bindValue($k, $v);
}
```

However I find this approach cumbersome. **Is there a design pattern for this situation?** What is the canonical way to handle situations where the code must branch in two separate locations on the same `if` condition?

Comment: what programming language is this? PHP?

Comment: The language in the examples is PHP, but the question is language-agnostic.

Comment: Why the downvote? How might I improve the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may sound trivial, but I would simply create a variable holding the condition to be tested twice

```
$is_normal_user = $user['type'] != 'admin';
```

and then use that variable in the `if` checks. This not only makes the code more readable and easier to maintain (the variable name describes what the check is supposed to do, avoiding confusion about `==` vs `!=`), but can also improve performance in case the check is more complex.

Comment: can improve performance?? can you please tell me HOW?? :/

Comment: @DeepakSharma - checking the state of a boolean variable is one of the simpler things a program can do. It's much faster than pulling a variable out of a hash, and then doing a string comparison. In this case, with the small number of tests, the user-visible performance difference is negligible, but if the check were more complicated (or executed many times) it might start to matter.

Comment: for the **if ( $user['type']!='admin')** check u r creating a bool var ?? its already checked in inline code and not using the same check again in code, then whats the use to create a new variable?

Comment: @DeepakSharma Maybe my answer was not 100% clear. The idea is to creae the variable before the if conditons, and then using that variable in the if condition, i.e. `if ($is_normal_user)`. This makes it more readable (no negation in the condition) and in cases where the check is more computationally intensive than a simple hash lookup will also improve performance. Of course, if you are not using the same check again, than that's pointless, but wasn't the question about checking it twice?

Comment: @tobias_k yes you r right.. but i will say its call optimization.. Its not really related to performance.. but yes somewhere somehow its also effect the computational cycle.

Comment: Thank you. After much pondering, I see that this really is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a general pattern to this, although there are a limited number of solutions.  One solution is to recognize that you have two conditions which determine how many rows you get back, and then allow both of those conditions to be tested on sql backend.

```
-- Normal users:
SELECT * FROM Foobar WHERE user_id=:user_id;

-- Admins:
SELECT * FROM Foobar;

-- actual query
SELECT * FROM Foobar WHERE user_id=:user_id Or is_admin=1;
```

Comment: This could force the query optimizer into a suboptimal plan, because it must account for all possible situations. For admins, it should scan the whole table, but for users it should be making use of an index on user_id. If you OR them together, it must use the least common denominator: the full table scan, which is VERY BAD for normal users.

Comment: @infogulch: the query optimizer should be smarter than that.  See SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d5e86/2

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't count because the expression can be analyzed and optimized statically. But look at what happens to the execution plan when you change `or 1=2` to `or 1=1`: it goes from index seek to a table (aka "clustered index") scan. When you prepare a statement it has to choose exactly **one** of those beforehand, it can't recompile every time you exec the statement. See this excellent article [Smart Logic](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/obfuscation/smart-logic) that explains this exact situation.